# Exception Handling: What level to put it at

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

This is a bit of a general and conceptual question, not sure if it is in scope for SO, but I'll give it a shot.

I've run into situations like the following several times and I've never been sure how to handle it.

I have several functions that call each other in some hierachy. I want to handle bad inputs to the functions, but some functions will never call other functions directly.

For example, I have this function:

```
def getDataSourcesOfTypes(username, datatypes):
    if len(datatypes) < 1:
        raise ValueError("Please specify at least 1 datatype")
    http = authorizeHttp(username)
    ...snip...
    return data_sources_list
```

Which calls this:

```
def authorizeHttp(username):
    if not isinstance(username, str):
        raise ValueError("Invalid username.")
    credential_json = Database.getCredential(username)
    ...snip...
```

Which in turn calls this:

```
def getCredential(username):
    Database.connection.row_factory = sqlite.Row  # @UndefinedVariable
    cursor = Database.connection.cursor()
    ...snip...
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        raise LookupError("Username does not exist.")
    else:
       ...snip...
```

Now, for `username`, I have several opportunities to catch a bad one (i.e. not a string, nonexistant, etc). Obviously I can't catch the error of it not appearing in the database until I call the last function, but I can catch a `None` as early as the first function.

The question is: Where is the best place to catch an exception? At the level farthest down the hierarchy? As soon as you can?

Again, I think this might be too much of a subjective question for SO, but I am really curious about what is considered the best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are general adviceses to follow.

- Catch error in the place, where a fix is possible
- Do not ignore exception even if possible (no `except: pass`)
- Log them
- Do not use too-broad cases like `except:` or `except Exception:`
- Use different exception blocks for different exception types
- Use `else` and `finally` where needed
- Exception is an **exceptional** behavior, do not make it a logical
  part of your app

Here's a [good article](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/) about exception handling. [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except) also have best-practices. And the one [from the past](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/21/robust-exception-handling/) (but is still has the valid info).

Considering the place where to catch them. Well, there are different possibilities here.

1. You don't use any of these functions anywhere else in the code.
   In this case, look at this problem with the intent "I need to inform user what has gone wrong. And that's all". In this case it is possible to catch the exception at the highest level possible.
2. When these functions are widly used in the code, you need a different approach. Raise exceptions as you do, and catch them at the place, where anything can be done to return to the normal program execution if this is a desired behavior. Alternatively, it's sometimes needed to reraise exception. For example:

   ```
   try:
        credential_json = Database.getCredential(username)
   except LookupError as le:
        log.warning(le)
        renew_token()  # (example) try to fix the problem somehow
        credential_json = Database.getCredential(username) # retry
        # note, that the next possible LookupError is not handled here.
   finally:
        check_data(credential_json)
   return credential_json
   ```
3. You are writing reusable code. In this case it is complicated. A
   deep understanding of your workflow is required. Your code must
   provide custom exceptions, exception handlers, which can be easily
   overridden, control the returning values, provide fallbacks and so on.

   ```
   def function_with_handler(data, error_handler=_handler, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
           do_stuff()
       except CustomError as such_problem:
           # log.level(such_problem)
           _handler(such_problem, data, *args, **kwargs)
   ```

Also, sometimes it is actually a good idea to add an option to `fail_silently = True`.

It is generally a good practice to read source code of large projects. For example, look at how `Django` is dealing with [exceptions](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/exceptions.py).

Comment: "Exception is an exceptional behavior" - in some other language. In Python it is advised that "better to ask for forgiveness than permission", and it avoids nasty TOCTOU vulnerabilities

Comment: Yes, race-condition is a good example when to use `try:except` instead of checks.

Comment: _"Do not use too-broad cases like except: or except Exception"_    Often a particular API can throw a dozen possible exceptions and there's no difference in how your code needs to or even can respond, other than to deal with the failure in a general way and communicate/log the particular type of exception and message details associated with it for the purposes of troubleshooting.   I don't want to write a dozen different exception blocks that essentially all do the same thing. Different blocks should only be used if your code's response to them is different.

Comment: @wojtow, I would say that `except (ValueError, CustomError, ..) as e:` is preferable in this case. It explictly shows which exceptions you are expecting there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, as a general rule, closest to the real source of the error, where it can (likely) be handled appropriately. If that's a bad input, then at the level of the input (perhaps chaining it in the way). If that's an expected exception for a missing key in a dictionary, then catch it right away. etc.

But of course, there is much more to it.